# Is it possible to have multiple parent with one child relationship in Salesforce?

Tags: relationships, master-detail

I have one object that contains fields that stored decimal and it already have Account as parent object.Because I want to Roll up Summary to do calculation on that (SUM) those field,I need to create Parent object.

Is that possible to have two parent for one child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of two parents:

[image: example]

But be aware that by having both relationships set to Master-Detail (so the rollup can be done across either relationship) if either of the parent objects is deleted the child object is automatically deleted. This is often useful (for [association objects)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) but may or may not be in your case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a roll-up summary, you need a `Master-Detail` relationship. You can define up to 2 of those per custom object.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en_US